# how to load image to uiimageview

Tags: ios, image, uiimage, load

how to load image to uiimageview from a custom folder

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; // Get documents folder
    NSString*ext= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/Imagenes/30775.png"];
    NSString *dataPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:ext];
     //option 1 
     UIImage * myImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile: dataPath];
    _img.image = myImage
    ///option 2
    UIImageView * myImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: myImage];
    _img = myImageView;
    ///option 3
    NSData *imgData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:dataPath]];
    _img.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imgData];
```

i try 3 options but not working
any idea ?

the image is loading from a custom folder
i checked the path and is correct but not load

Answer (score 1):

Your path @"/Imagenes/30775.png" seems to be wrong. Double check it. Otherwise following should work

```
 UIImage * myImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile: dataPath];
_img.image = myImage
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 NSString*ext= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/Imagenes/30775.png"];
```

Your path is wrong.I guess the Imagenes is a group in your project. So xcode is not create a folder in your project main folder. The groups is only helps you to view the files easily in the xcode program.
Also you don't need `stringWithFormat`.

Try this;

```
 NSString*ext= @"30775.png";
```